# Are VBA and BASIC the same thing?

Tags: vba, basic

I was thinking about learning BASIC, because a friend told me that that is the language being used in Excel, but when I searched on net, it showed that VBA is the language being used to code in Excel. So I was confused whether both of them are the same thing. If they are not is it that both of them can be used to code in Excel? If it is so, which is better for a person oriented with OOP based Java language?

Comment: Have a look at the wiki page, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC. No, they're not the same thing. Your friend is mistaken, Basic is not used by Excel. Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) is used to create macros in Excel and other Microsoft applications. Visual Basic (VB) is a similar language (also created by Microsoft), with the main difference being that VB programs can be run outside of Microsoft applications.

Comment: You could learn some very simplified BASIC by doing some programming on a TI-83+

Comment: Basic is a language created in 1964. There are many implementations of it. Built in to Windows are Visual Basic .NET and Visual Basic Script. Built in to Office is Visual Basic for Applications. They all have the basic constructs of the Basic language. You can see some sample programs here https://pastebin.com/u/dcandygmailcom. Basic is the most widely used language in the world, however it is not widely used by professional programmers due to academic hatred of Microsoft who supply all the popular Basics (there are other Basics like Liberty Basic not from Microsoft).

Comment: Microsoft Basics are based on COM and .NET can use COM. Excel is a COM server. Any COM program can control Excel from outside it. Excel's macro language is VBA and it runs inside Excel (so it is quick) but it controls Excel using the same objects as outside programs. So Excel hosts the VBA language using COM and also makes Excel's objects available to any COM program.

Answer (score 13):

## VBA is one BASIC

There are many different languages on the BASIC family and not a "standard" BASIC. VBA is acronym for Visual Basic for Applications. In its case, the name actually tells much of the story.

The first BASIC language was developed in 1964 as a general purpose language, relatively easy for non-scientists. Since then, many variations emerged. Diferent versions of BASIC were available on the ROM of most microcomputers on the 80's (MSX, Commodore etc.) and were the main languages used by hobbyists programmers. Each version had different syntax and semantics and moderate effort was required to port programs between plataforms using different BASICs.

In 1992, Microsoft developed a version for Windows that combined BASIC code with Drag'n'Drop UI design, and named it Visual Basic. Thus **Visual Basic** is a version of **BASIC** featurning **Visual** UI design for developing MS Windows programs.

When Microsoft decided to implement macro languages for the Microsof Office products these were BASIC variants (WordBasic, AccessBasic...) but later all these were unified to use a single language - derived from Visual Basic 6.0, and named Visual Basic for Applications. It was later adopted in some other non-Microsoft applications such as Corel Draw and WordPerfect. Thus, **Visual Basic for Applications** is a version of **BASIC** featurning **Visual** UI design for extending MS Office (and certain other) **Applications**.

So, all in all, VBA is just a (very specialized) version of the BASIC language.

Comment: Great explanation! :)